How can I convert this script that compatible with Hyva thme in Magento 2?
I need to convert this given script that compatible with hyva theme
require(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/cache',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
    ],
    function (cartCache, totalsProcessor, quote) {
        cartCache.clear('cartVersion');
        totalsProcessor.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());
    }
);

Can any one guid me how can i convert it

Step 1: Alpine.js Setup
Hyvä theme typically encourages using Alpine.js for frontend interactions. You’ll need to integrate this script within an Alpine.js component or directly within the page if you're not using a component structure.
Step 2: Converted Script
Here's how you can rewrite your Magento 2 script in a way that's compatible with the Hyvä theme using Alpine.js and native JavaScript
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.data('cartTotalsHandler', () => ({
        init() {
            this.clearCartCache();
            this.estimateTotals();
        },
        clearCartCache() {
            require(['Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/cache'], (cartCache) => {
                cartCache.clear('cartVersion');
            });
        },
        estimateTotals() {
            require(['Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default', 'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'], 
            (totalsProcessor, quote) => {
                totalsProcessor.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());
            });
        }
    }));
});

How to Use It
You can place this script inside your template or layout file within an x-data Alpine.js component as follows:
<div x-data="cartTotalsHandler" x-init="init()">
    <!-- Your Hyvä HTML code here -->
</div>

Explanation:
Alpine.data('cartTotalsHandler', () => ({...})):
This sets up an Alpine.js component named
cartTotalsHandler.
init():
This function is automatically called when the Alpine component is initialized, and it clears the cart cache and estimates totals.
clearCartCache() and estimateTotals():
These are the methods that handle the specific Magento 2 logic using require to load Magento modules.
This should make your code compatible with the Hyvä theme in Magento 2, following best practices for using Alpine.js.
